# why does ^~ not stop processing routing rules in nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver, url-rewriting

So I've got 2 routes, and the first one doesn't stop the route matching, as the docs say it should:

```
location ^~ /p/ {
    root /www/domain.com/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /path/index.html;
}

location ^~ /v/ {
    root /www/domain.com/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /path/index.html;
}

location ^~ / {
    root /www/domain.com/php_www/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~* \.(?:php|html)$ {   
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        auth_basic "Staging";
        auth_basic_user_file /www/.htpasswd;

}
```

So if I have a url like this:

```
http://domain.com/p/1234567890
```

It matches the last route and not the first route. The problem surfaced because one of our guys added a page to the application:

```
http://domain.com/privacy
```

This was picked up by the FIRST route?? Which is where the problem is coming from.

The problem I'm having is with ^~. In the docs, it says that once this matches, it will stop matching, however the last route is always the one that loads.

Any ideas?

Comment: For reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: I've been testing this for a while now. It appears that the problem is related to nginx not checking against the final "/" in the first route. So I can do ^~ /p and it works ok, but the /privacy page doesn't load. But it doesn't work when the route to match is ^~ /p/. It's something to do with this damn trailing slash!

Comment: Upgraded to latest nginx, and re-ordered some of the directives and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to latest nginx, and re-ordered some of the directives and everything is working now.